# How to perform join between on float type id column and one string having multiple ids seperated by comma

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have to join id of two sets where in on set has multiple ids and another table has only one id. My query is:

```
Select * from(Select('1301,1303,1305,1307,1309,1311,1313,1315') IDs from market group by market.Segment)P join DST d on   p.IDs = d.ID
```

One thing to note is '1301,1303,1305,1307,1309,1311,1313,1315' is value coming from dynamic query so I can not manipulate this value (to 1301,1303,1305,1307,1309,1311,1313,1315). 
In this query,d.ID is float type. This query does not work.

My aim is to find any record from DST table that has at least on id among ids 1301,1303,1305,1307,1309,1311,1313,1315.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - Joining tables where one of the columns is a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3771595/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` clause :

```
select m.*
from market m
where m.id in (1301,1303,1305,1307,1309,1311,1313,1315);
```

If `id`s are in string format then you can do :

```
select m.*
from market m cross apply
     dbo.string_split('1301,1303,1305,1307,1309,1311,1313,1315', ',') mm
where mm.value = m.id;
```

Comment: getting error -Invalid object name 'dbo.string_split'. on execution.I guess this function can only be used after from statement.